# DatabaseGenerated unique string annotation not working

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an Entity Framework 6 Code-First database maintained via migrations. My entity A is like this:

```
public class A {
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(6)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the DB to automatically populate the Code field with a unique code when inserting the new A object, without me worrying about race conditions.

However, when I try to add a new `A { Name = "a1" }` entry when populating the DB, the DB complaints that I `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Code', table 'A'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`.

If I try to add `A { Name = "a1", Code="abcdef" }` the error is the same.
The only way to "solve" it is to remove the "DatabaseGenerated" annotation.

What am I doing wrong? It is not possible to have db-generated unique strings, as currently happens for int IDs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1 AutoGenerated field on a database table and it must be a whole number type (i.e. int, bigint).  Strings can't be autogenerated like that.  If you want something unique here, just do a UniqueIdentifier or GUID as the field type instead of string and you can just assign a new Guid to it in code.  If you want it specifically to be a string, use a new Random() class to generate a random 6 characters, but you won't know if it is unique.  You'd have to manually verify that.